# Failed to connect to my Github Account with 2FA enabled after google authenticator reinstall

Tags: github

I had to get a new laptop and at the same time had to format my mobile where Google Authenticator was installed. Now when I try to login to my GitHub Account it asks for this 2FA option whereas I don't have it and also not sure what recovery keys its asking.

Is there anyone who has seen this issue. How can I get that bar code generated again for my account?

I have tried checking the internet but didn't find anything which could resolve this.

Have issue with only my Github Account.

Comment: There is now (Oct. 2022) an [improved account recovery flow in case of a lost 2FA device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199728/6309).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub provides [instructions for recovering access to your account](https://help.github.com/articles/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials/).

The first option it recommends is to use a recovery code¹, but it sounds like you don't have those. You would have received them when you first set up 2FA, and would have been prompted to put them in a safe place.

Another good option is to use your fallback phone number, assuming you configured one.

If neither of these options will work for you, please read the rest of the options listed on the page I linked above. You may need to contact [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact).

---

¹Note that you should also have received recovery codes for Google Authenticator itself. You should be able to use these to regain access to Google Autenticator which you can then use to log into GitHub.

Comment: I am trying to find if i have any recovery keys stored in my old laptop backup. Thanks for the path.

Comment: So i got them my verified key generated for the my user from an already connected node or workstation to my Github Account. Github staff were kind enough to disable the 2FA.